# Forzar salto al catch

Tags: java, try-catch

¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el salto, sin provocar una excepción, desde el interior del **try** al **catch**?
Por ejemplo:

```
try {

    // Código
    // ...
    //

    //Provocar salto al "catch" -> ¿otra opción?
    Integer.parseInt( "hola" );

} catch( Exception e ) {

    // Código
    // ...
    //
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente:

*El programa solicita la selección de un número de opción, pongamos del 1 al 5. Como espero un número, hago una conversión a tipo int de la entrada dentro del try, si falla, muestro un mensaje y llamo recursivamente a la función, hasta que obtiene un número válido. Ya fuera del try-catch (ya tengo un número), compruebo que el número este dentro de un intervalo, de otra forma, de nuevo muestro un mensaje y llamada recursiva... lo que quería era meter esta comprobación en el try, después de la conversión y saltar al catch si el número no estaba entre los esperados, por ahorrar unas líneas. Lo que tengo funciona, pero quiero mejorarlo.*

Por lo tanto lo que quiero saber es como forzar un salto al interior del catch sin forzar una excepción, si hay alguna forma prevista.

Comment: solo como curiosidad cual es la intension?

Comment: con un "break".

Comment: @Orici si llegaste a solucionar la pregunta que hiciste, podrías marcar la respuesta que se ayudo en solucionar. gracias

Comment: Las excepciones pueden llegar a ser costosas. Manten la validación del rango aparte, quizá uses mas lineas de código pero puede ser mas eficiente, que "ahorrartelas" y lanzar una excepción.

Comment: @Orici Te recomiendo que te familiarices con las diferentes [estructuras de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructuras_de_control) que existen en el lenguaje de programación Java y su —naturalmente— adecuado uso ... Y dejar de usar el bloque **`catch`** para un propósito distinto... porque de lo contrario estarás generando [**código espagueti**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_espagueti).

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el salto, sin provocar una excepción, desde el interior del `try` al `catch`?

No se puede forzar la ejecución del catch si no se ha lanzado un `Throwable`, es decir una excepción o un error, dentro de la sección `try`.

Esto se explica muy bien en el [JLS 14. Blocks and Statements 14.20. The try statement 14.20.1. Execution of try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1) y [14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista para lo que pregunta el OP la unica respuesta valida es la de Luiggi, ya que se menciona que no se provoque una excepción

Answer (score 5):

Buenas.

Puedes [lanzar una excepción](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) desde cualquier parte del programa, sin importar si es capturada por un `catch`. Para hacer esto debes crear la excepción y lanzarla con la palabra reservada `throw` de la siguiente manera:

```
throw new EmptyStackException();
```

Esto hará que el bloque `catch` con el tipo de la excepción adecuado se ejecute. Para ello se busca según la pila de llamadas al bloque que pueda capturarlo, si no hay, la Maquina virtual terminará la ejecución del programa al no lograr procesar el error ([propagación de excepciones](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html), [What is exception propagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633664/what-is-exception-propagation)).

Considera la siguiente imagen:

[image: Jerarquía de Errores en Java]

Puedes lanzar con `thow` cualquier clase que sea hija de Throwable. Si quieres lanzar una excepcion del tipo `Exception` pero no quieres procesarla debes declarar en la funcion donde se da la excecion que se debe capturar en un nivel superior (esto no es necesario para hijos de `RuntimeException`), esto es de la [siguiente manera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html):

```
public void FuncionQueNoProcesaExcepciones throws Exception, 
                                                  MiException {
    // ...
}
```

Ahora si quieres capturar una excepcion, la estructura de un manejador de excepciones contiene la palabras reservadas [try](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html), [catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html), [finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html). la estructura es la siguiente:

```
try {
    // codigo que podría lanzar excepciones. Puedes ser distintos
    // tipos como IOException, IndexOutOfBoundsException
} catch (IOException excepcion){
    // Este bloque solo se ejecuta cuando se lanza una excepcion 
    // del tipo IOException
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException excepcion){
    // Este bloque solo se ejecuta cuando se lanza una excepcion 
    // del tipo IndexOutOfBoundsException
} finally {
    // siempre se llama a finally, haya una excepcion o no.
}
```

Aclarando la función del bloque try-catch, respondiendo a:

> ¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el salto, sin provocar una excepción, desde el interior del try al catch?

Estas son las opciones:

- Usar `throw` para ejecutar el `catch`. Esto te saca del flujo normal del programa.
- Usar un método en el `catch`, de manera que se pueda llamar sin lanzar una excepción. De esta forma puedes llamarlo desde cualquier parte, incluso dentro del `try` (obvio es una método).

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String texto = "Desde el try";
      try {
          // codigo
          procesaExcepcion(texto);

          // si se llamara desde el catch ...
          throw new Exception();
      } catch (Exception c) {
          texto = "Desde el catch";
          procesaExcepcion(texto, c);
      }
  }

  public static void procesaExcepcion(Object... contexto) {
      // hacer cosas para procesar la excepcion
      System.out.println(contexto[0]);
  }
  ```
- Usar funciones de reflexión y marcos de trabajo para manipulación de bytecodes (esta es la única forma de ejecutar el `catch` sin lanzar una excepción), pero esto no es para nada fácil.

Ahora, tu problema no necesita una llamada recursiva

> "muestro un mensaje y llamo recursivamente a la función"

La forma correcta de validar una entrada es mediante el uso del ciclo do-while, de la siguiente manera

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
int variable = -1;

do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        variable = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );
    } catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        // no es necesario poner algo aqui
    }
} while (variable < 1 || variable > 5);

System.out.print(variable);
```

El codigo de arriba declara e inicializa una variable que guarda el numero que deseas validar. Al intentar convertir con `parseInt` hay dos opciones: se convierte o lanza una excepcion.

- Si se convierte, el while del ciclo valida que se encuentre entre los valores deseados, si no, se vuelve a leer la entrada.
- En caso de excepcion, la variable vale -1 por lo que no es un valor valido y se repite el ciclo.

Ahora, si quieres un codigo mas corto puedes cambiar el bloque:

```
try {
        System.out.print("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        variable = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );
} catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        // no es necesario poner algo aqui
}
```

por

```
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
variable = sc.nextInt();
```

Por ultimo si tienes problemas con las lineas ;) siempre puedes escribirlo todo en una sola sin espacios:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int v=-1;do{while(!s.hasNextInt())s.next();v=s.nextInt();}while(v<1||v>5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Para este caso te recomendaría que te crearas excepciones propias extendiendo de la clase [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
public class ExcepcionPropia extends Exception {
    public ExcepcionPropia(String mensaje) {
        super(mensaje);
    }
}
```

quedando tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
try{
     if (numEntrada == valor) {
          throw new ExcepcionPropia();
     }
}catch(ExcepcionPropia e){
     // Aqui recoges la excepcion que has forzado
}catch(Excepcion e){
     // Aqui se recogen las demás excepciones
}
```

en el que podrás terminar el `try-catch` cuando no se cumpla que el numeroEntrada sea igual al valor deseado, lanzando de esta forma la excepción propia y recogiendola en el bloque `catch` correspondiente, ejecutando las acciones deseadas dentro de este bloque.

Comment: En tu código corres la excepción dentro del try, y él esta pidiendo que se haga desde afuera, cosa que no es posible.

Comment: @maguz el ha puesto esto "¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el salto, sin provocar una excepción, desde el interior del try al catch?" igual lo he interpretado mal pero pone desde el interior del try-catch lo único que mi respuesta obliga a lanzar una excepción, pero sin provocar una excepción creo que no es posible lo que pide

Comment: toda la razón, me disculpo

Comment: tranquilo, no pasa nada, también podía haberlo interpretado mal yo. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

La función del try... catch

En la parte del try es una sección de código donde la o las sentencias intentarán capturar un posible error. Si se produce se tiene que capturar donde aparece la parte del catch. 
Ejemplo:

```
try{
     // Instrucciones que se intentan ejecutar, Si se produce una
     // situación inesperada se lanza una excepción.
}catch(tipoExcepcion e){
     // Instrucciones para tratar esta excepción.
}catch(otroTipoExcepcion e){
     // Instrucciones para tratar esta excepción.
}
```

Si querés forzar el error, porque se introdujo mal el número, no hace falta que este dentro de un try ... catch. La función try catch no vale la pena usarlo para este caso. 
Podrías agregar un if para ver que no cumple con el valor esperado y mostrar un mensaje indicando eso.

Ejemplo:

```
if(numero >= 6){
    System.out.println("Numero incorrecto!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El fin de un `try-catch` es éste, si lo que se pretende es que no se haga nada llegado el caso pues simplemente dejarlo  vacío:

```
try{
}catch(SomeException e){}
```

Aunque en mi opinión no es recomendado ya que en tal caso de tener un comportamiento inesperado, éstas excepciones son las que nos ayudan a depurar el código.

Si lo que quiere es saltarse un `catch` **ÚNICAMENTE** en un caso en particular, algo similar a un  `break xyz;` para una iteración, eso no es posible.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lanzar una excepcion con

> throw new Exception();
>   Pero me parece que lo mejor es que hagas un metodo con lo que necesitas hacer en el fallo, o un metodo para saber que hacer en el try, esto para mejorar la lectura

```
try {

    // Código
    // ...
    //

    //Provocar salto al "catch" -> ¿otra opción?
   int valor= Integer.parseInt( tuCadenaConNumero );
   if(valor<1 || valor> 5)
      mandarErrorYRegresar(tuCadenaConNumero );

} catch( Exception e ) {
    mandarErrorYRegresar(tuCadenaConNumero );
    // Código
    // ...
    //
}
```

[...]

```
public void mandarErrorYRegresar(String tuCadenaConNumero ){
   System.out.println("El valor '"+tuCadenaConNumero +"' No es valido");
   //codigo para volver a pedir el numero;
   PedirNumero();
}
```

o dentro del try llamas una funcion que haga todas las validaciones, esta funcion manda excepcion cuando algo no esta dentro de lo necesario

Answer (score 1):

En base a lo que escribes que quieres hacer a mi se me ocurrió resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  // needed for Scanner

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        FnConTry();
    }

    public static void FnConTry(){
        try {

            // Codigo
            // ...
            //
            //Solicito un numero
            // 1. Create a Scanner using the InputStream available.
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
            // 2. Don't forget to prompt the user
            System.out.print( "Escribe un numero: " );
            // 3. Use the Scanner to read a line of text from the user.
            String n = scanner.nextLine();
            int numero = 0;

            //Provocar salto al "catch" -> otra opcion?
            numero = Integer.parseInt( n );
             if(numero >= 1 && numero <= 5){
                System.out.println("Numero Valido");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("El numero no esta en el rango!!");
                FnConTry();
            }

        } catch( Exception e ) {

            System.out.println("\nRecuerde que debe introducir un numero");
            FnConTry();
            // Codigo
            // ...
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que dices de enviar al `catch` sin lanzar una excepción, no le encuentro sentido, no se si quieres ahorrar recursos o algo así... si logras descubrir como hacerlo comparte la respuesta por favor.

Comment: Tengo algo similar a lo que planteas, solo que el if - else esta después del try - catch, de momento no encuentro una forma mas sencilla o "adecuada" de hacerlo.

Comment: Ok, si encuentras como hacerlo :) serias tan amable de actualizar para saber como.

Answer (score 1):

puedes ejecutar forzar disparando una excepción  o ejecutar instrucciones con finally

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            throw new NumberFormatException("Error formato del numero");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            System.out.println("Algo finalmente");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Hay alguna forma de forzar el salto, sin provocar una excepción,
>   desde el interior del try al catch?

Precisamente el catch es creado para capturar un tipo de excepción, si no generas un error no se va a forzar el salto al bloque `catch`:

```
try {

    // Código
    // ...
    //

    //Provocar salto al "catch" -> ¿otra opción?
    Integer.parseInt( "hola" );

} catch( Exception e ) {

    // Código
    // ...
    //
}
```

---

En cambio puedes lanzar una excepción creando tu exception:

```
public class MyCustomExcepcion extends Exception{

    public MyCustomExcepcion(String excute)
    {
        super(excute);
    }
    public String getMessage()
    {
        return super.getMessage();
    }
}
```

La cual usarías de esta forma:

```
 MyCustomExcepcion myCustomException = new MyCustomExcepcion("mi error personalizado.");

    try {    
        ...
        ...
        ...    
        //Provocar salto al "catch" -> ¿otra opción?
        //Integer.parseInt( "hola" );
        //Esta sería la opción:
        throw myCustomExcepcion();

    } catch(MyCustomExcepcion e) {    
       ...
       ...          
    } catch(Exception e) {    
       ...
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Bueno como te lo comentan arriba, puedes hacer un `throw new RuntimeException("Mensaje")` dentro de try y eso lo va mandar directo al catch

Te pongo un ejemplo más claro de como hacerlo directamente

```
try {

    // Código
    // ...
    //

    If(<<condicion>>)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("No me gusta este número")
    }
    Integer.parseInt( "hola" );

} catch( Exception e ) {

    // Código
    // ...
    //
}
```

Comment: Hola @Cristian. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! Edité tu respuesta para que esté indentada correctamente... Pero, como bien estás mencionando, esto mismo fue parte de una respuesta previa, y no veo que se esté agregando nada nuevo con esta respuesta, aunque quizás me equivoque, por lo que sería bueno que menciones si cuál sería la diferencia con lo que ya se respondió